# Need to determine screen resolution to display necessary items on web page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-interface

I have a peculiar scenario, where in I have to display extra elements on my **webpage** if the user is using a **24 inch monitor**. 
I know we could determine the height and width using Javascript, but how do we relay that information to the code on the server before rendering the webpage itself?

- **Determining the Height/Width of display - Client Side.**
- **Code execution code behind - server side.**

How do I handle this sort of a situation?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions. I really need suggestions on this :)

Comment: Why not set your height/width with a percentage so they can scale accordingly?

Comment: You can't determine the **physical** dimensions of the display. You can determine the **resolution** of the display. Is that what you want?

Comment: @egrunin yes that is what i would need

Answer (score 3):

If you want the **resolution**, rather than the **physical dimension**, [here's an example](http://forums.asp.net/p/1203356/2127889.aspx#2127889) that creates a custom control to report the size.

You put this (or something like it) on the first page the user hits, and then store the result in session variables.

Answer (score 1):

what you want to is a little difficult but I had the same situation. I would do it this way;

In order to get the width and height of the screen, user must load javascript to their browser. Then, you can get the width and height of the user's screen. I would suggest you to use a JQUERY

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

then you can call C# functions from JQUERY if you declare your C# functions [WebMethod]. In your webmethod functions, you can render your asp.net and return the rendered code.

When the JQUERY calls your webmethod, finishes the job and returns the html, paste that html to divs/panel/container....

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to use CSS media queries.  This will hide an element with the ID of "myControlID" when the user's screen is less than 768 pixels wide.  This will also allow the user to resize their screen to greater than 768 pixels wide and the element will become visible without posting back to the server.

```
@media all and (max-width: 768) {

    #myControlID {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

}
```